# Why is there a large gap between Begin PreRenderComplete and End PreRenderComplete events?

Tags: asp.net, performance, events, prerender

I'd like to know what can cause this kind of disparity between the begin and end PreRendercomplete events or how I migh go about locating the bottleneck.

```
aspx.page   End PreRender   0.193179639923915   0.001543
aspx.page   Begin PreRenderComplete 0.193206263076064   0.000027
aspx.page   End PreRenderComplete   1.96926008935549    1.776054
aspx.page   Begin SaveState 2.13108461902679    0.161825
```

**EDIT**

Here is some more detail about the trace that was generated

```
aspx.page   Begin PreRenderComplete 0.200593573416824   0.000028
PR-S                                0.200606270612464   0.000013
PR-complete                         0.200622654090709   0.000016
PR-E                                1.97799207367323    1.777369
aspx.page   End PreRenderComplete   1.97805105419491    0.000059
aspx.page   Begin SaveState         2.11171607104531    0.133665
```

The code behind:

```
Private Sub _Default6_PreRenderComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
    Trace.Write("PR-complete")
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRenderComplete(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Trace.Write("PR-S")
    MyBase.OnPreRenderComplete(e)
    Trace.Write("PR-E")
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how else to trace what might be running on the pre-render complete event.  are there any other type of controls or functs that run at this point in the page lifecycle?

**More Info**

Part of this delay appears to be related to having ajax controls on the page.  I'm unsure why they are causing such a large gap in the load time but clearly they are.

Comment: I suggest you to start disabling different parts of the page. When you disable one piece that eliminate the bottleneck, at least you will have the problem isolated.

Comment: Also check how much ViewState is being generated. It can take a while (relatively speaking) to encrypt it and create a HMAC for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to throw out the tried and true answer. Profile profile profile. That should give you all the information you need to see where the process is locked on.

Comment: Marked it correct because at the end of hte day, while still don't know what is causing this, and I have a lot of experience profileing, I'd say that this really is the only solution even though it may not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an event handler attached to a `PreRenderComplete` event that's taking a long time. I would start by searching your code for references to `PreRenderComplete` and going from there.

Comment: I'm not able to bind to the prerendercomplete event as far as I can tell so that's not causing the issue.

Comment: The `PreRenderComplete` event is available on the Page itself: user controls and the like cannot bind to it, but you can bind to it in the page itself.